I cant use my sol in my wallet
There’s a smart contract in the wallet to send any funds out of the wallet , I asked a different dev to do it for me because the wallet was compromised , what I can do boys?  I cant send my sol  it's frozen
SOL ADDY : 4VGbxoF4wJjnqugQVFaYmCUxTP6MNXfWidKHTjqry63W
